# How to rename Windows network adapter via batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename, nic, network-interface

I'm making a script with some network functions and to work it needs a specific label at the network adapter, but in the windows system the network adapters do not use the same name as default in all versions.

I know that I can use both the "netsh" in batch or powershell to rename the network adapter, but I can not know the current name of the adapter.

This is the command that i know to rename the adapter in batch:
`netsh interface set interface name="Conexão Local 2" newname="Rede"`

I want to use batch because the script was written in batch language.

I have the command to get the names of all network adpaters:
`netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces`

It returns:

```
Índ     Met         MTU          Estado                Nome
---  ----------  ----------  ------------  ---------------------------
  1          75  4294967295  connected     Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
  4          25        1500  disconnected  Conexão Sem Fio
 11          25        1500  disconnected  Conexão Local* 9
 15          35        1500  connected     Conexão Local* 2
  2          25        1500  disconnected  Conexão Local* 14
```

I could use this to get the current name by the "Índ" showing the list at the prompt and a question to get the "Índ" number, then store the current name in a variable. I need to rename the wireless connection and the wired adapter.

**EDIT**

I made some progress and arrive to this code:

```
chcp 1252>NUL
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set numlinha=1
FOR /F "skip=3 tokens=5,* delims= " %%A IN ('netsh interface ipv4 show interface') DO (
    echo !numlinha! %%A %%B>> te.txt
    set /a numlinha=!numlinha!+1
)
```

And this returns to the file test.txt:

```
1 Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
2 Conexão de Rede sem Fio
3 Conexão de Rede sem Fio 2
4 Conexão Local
5 Conexão de Rede Bluetooth
```

Now the user will choose the adapter by the line number and after that the script needs to get all the line without the numbers.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you want. Do you want the script to automatically rename it, or do you want to add names to rename to after getting a list first?

Comment: I want to select the interface from the list shown and the script rename to the names "Rede" (for the wired) and "Wifi" (for the wireless). I think it can be done with "for" but I do not know how. If possible it would be better that the script detect the adapter and rename automatically.